# How would you use this script to get/set cookies? Small script

Tags: javascript, cookies, get, set

https://gist.github.com/4149633

Small script to get/set cookies in js, how can you use it? It was posted on Chris Coyier's CSS-Tricks site in the snippets library.

What's the benefit of this script? How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty easy:

```
_.cookie( 'myCookie', 1 ); // (Set a cookie)
_.cookie( 'myCookie' ); // return 1 (Get a cookie)
_.cookie( 'myCookie', null ); // (Delete a cookie)
_.cookie( 'secondCookie', 'a value', { expires: 1000 }) // Set a cookie that will expire in 1 second
```

You can also set the cookie's `path` and `domain` using the last form with the option object.

Answer (score 0):

create one js with this functions

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {

     if (exdays) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
         }
         else var expires = "";
         document.cookie = c_name+"="+escape(value)+expires";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name ) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

and just make call of functions like

```
setCookie("cookieName","cookieValue",365);
```

and

```
getCookie("cookieName");
```

but make sure that you can't get cookies which is send from server with `HTTPONLY` or `SECURE` attribute.